# How to import const char* API to C#?

Tags: c#, dllimport

Given this C API declaration how would it be imported to C#?

```
const char* _stdcall z4LLkGetKeySTD(void);
```

I've been able to get this far:

```
   [DllImport("zip4_w32.dll",
       CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
       EntryPoint = "z4LLkGetKeySTD",
       ExactSpelling = false)]
   private extern static const char* z4LLkGetKeySTD();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
   [DllImport("zip4_w32.dll",
       CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
       EntryPoint = "z4LLkGetKeySTD",
       ExactSpelling = false)]
   private extern static IntPtr z4LLkGetKeySTD();
```

You can then convert the result to a String by using Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  You will still need to free the memory for the IntPtr using the appropriate Marshal.Free* method.

Comment: How do you know which Marshal.Free* method should be used?

Comment: @thelaughingdm, it depends on how the memory was allocated.  The Marshal.FreeCoTaskMemAlloc frees a native CoTaskMemAlloc.  Each one works with a particular native method

Answer (score 4):

Always use C++ const char* or char* and not std::string.

Also keep in mind that char in C++ is a sbyte in C#
and unsigned char is a byte in C#.

It is advisable to use unsafe code when dealing with DllImport.

```
[DllImport("zip4_w32.dll",
   CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
   EntryPoint = "z4LLkGetKeySTD",
   ExactSpelling = false)]
 private extern static sbyte* or byte* z4LLkGetKeySTD();

 void foo()
 {
   string res = new string(z4LLkGetKeySTD());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use 'string' instead of 'const char *'.

Edit: This is dangerous for the reason JaredPar explained.  If you don't want a free, don't use this method.

Comment: You took the words out my mouth!

Comment: Definately don't use String.  If the return of a function is a String the CLR will attempt to CoTaskMemFree the native pointer which is likely not what the user wants here

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx bottom of the paragrah under figure 8

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about this.  Answer and I'll be sure to vote you up!