# Rewrite Delphi DLL-calls in c#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, pinvoke

I want to write a DMX Lightcontrol software in C#. My problem is that I've to rewrite the DLL-calls from Delphi to C#. Following code shows my attempts:

//Delphi-Code:

```
function GetDMXInterface: pchar; stdcall; external 'DMX510.dll';
function SetLevel(a: array of byte): boolean; stdcall; external 'DMX510.dll';
function GetMaxChannels: integer; external 'DMX510.dll';
```

//My own C#-Code:

```
[DllImport("DMX510.DLL")]
public static extern char* GetDMXInterface();
[DllImport("DMX510.DLL")]
public static extern Boolean SetLevel(Byte[] bytearray);
[DllImport("DMX510.DLL")]
public static extern int GetMaxChannels();
```

Next question how to convert the char pointer returned from GetDMXInterface() to a String

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you have this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508227/how-to-import-const-char-api-to-c

Sounds perfect for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, but I don't know if it works because I cannot test it:

```
[DllImport("DMX510.DLL")]
public static extern StringBuilder GetDMXInterface();
```

---

Or try

```
[DllImport("DMX510.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDMXInterface();
```

and then

```
IntPtr ptr = GetDMXInterface(); 
string msg = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
```

Comment: public static extern StringBuilder GetDMXInterface(); does work! Thanks!

Comment: @pbcoder: yeah, my first answer ;) I'm glad I helped you to solve your trouble :)

Comment: Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[GetMaxChannels()]; byteArray[0] = 75; SetLevel(byteArray); throws exceptions any solution for this problem?