# Importing DLL functions in c# code

Tags: c#, c++, c, dllimport, extern

I have a DLL, whose functions i want to use in my c# code
Here are the functions of that DLL :

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllimport)
  const char* __stdcall ZAJsonRequestA(const char *szReq);

  __declspec(dllimport)
  const wchar_t* __stdcall ZAJsonRequestW(const wchar_t *szReq);

  __declspec(dllimport)
  const BSTR __stdcall ZAJsonRequestBSTR(BSTR sReq);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to use it in c# project, as this dll seems to be in other language ?

Comment: Shouldn't `__declspec(dllimport)` be `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: i copied this from the documentation of the dll.
And, in that dll, dllimport is used not dllexport

Comment: teka a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845128/marshaling-byval-c-structure-as-return-value-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C) on Code Project for an in depth explanation

A small sample from the linked article is as shown below

To call a function, say **methodName**

```
int __declspec(dllexport) methodName(int b)
{
      return b;
}
```

Include the class library (MethodNameLibrary.dll) containing the above method as shown below in c#

```
class Program
{
   [DllImport(@"c:\MethodNameLibrary.dll")]
   private static extern int methodName(int b);
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(methodName(3));
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i try to invoke the function, it goes out of the block and the following statements donot get executed.

My declaration is like this :
[DllImport("FANselect.dll", EntryPoint = "ZAJsonRequestA")]
private static extern string ZAJsonRequestA(string szReq);

and i try to invoke it using :

string sResult = ZAJsonRequestA(sRequest);

This appears fine to me, but i am not getting the result

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Please have a look the following [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/508227/1012641) for help with the declaration

Answer (score 0):

Use [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) and [MarshalAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attributes.